# fswatch + rsync alternative or better inplementation

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, rsync, fswatch

I'm trying to watch a folder, and its subfolders for any changes in the files (HTML/CSS/JS/Etc). Once a file has changed, I want to upload it to a mounted drive from a remote server. Currently, I am using this in terminal:

```
fswatch -o ~/Desktop/Site/ | xargs -n1 sh ~/Documents/App\ Syncs/rsync_files.sh
```

rsync_files.sh:

```
rsync -rvzut --info=progress2 --delete-after --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/Users/ME/Documents/App\ Syncs/exclude_list.txt /Users/ME/Desktop/Site/ /Volumes/devroot$/Site;
```

The thought is that the fswatch will call the rsync each time there is a change in the file structure. It works, but it is VERY slow, esp over a crappy connection.

My question is, am I doing this right or is there a better solution for what I'm trying to accomplish? Can my rsync command be better optimized? Is there an app already made that will do this very thing for me?

Basically I want to mimic the file panel in Dreamweaver 2014 without having to use Dreamweaver. My setup is Sublime Text 3 and Codekit 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on where the bottleneck is, which is not clear in your question.  One thing though: if the connection is "crappy", I'd worry about fixing the connection before trying to tune `rsync`.

As far as `fswatch` is concerned, you are already using `-o`, so I devise no further way to improve its performance.  Maybe I would increase the latency value (`-l`): the command in your question will output events with a maximum frequency of 1 second.  Tune it to a higher value: start with a value on the same order of magnitude of the amount of time taken by the synchronisation job to finish.

As far as `rsync` is concerned, you may find room for some improvement.  Start asking yourself the following questions (and then google about it):

- Is `rsync` the best option?
- Would whole-file copy (`-W`) make sense?
- Does compression (`-z`) make sense?
- Does in-place synchronisation (`--inplace`) make sense?

If your connection is *slow*, start using `-z` and `--inplace` and see whether `rsync` performance improves.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll play around with the options to see what works best.